# Ionic cordova application will not install properly to Android device

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I updated everything I can think of on my machine. The app builds fine to iOS and was able to release it to the store.

I removed and re-added the Android platform and tried various build flags. I get a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message with no errors. I generated a signed bundle with the same keystore. Everything looks good in Android Studio event log when I run app to a device or emulator. I get a Launch succeeded message. The app icon gets added to the device, but it never launches. When I tap the app icon, I get a toast message saying Application not installed.

I don't see any errors anywhere. The app deployed fine for me 4 months ago. I've since updated my machine and can't get it running again with the current configuration.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (/Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.16
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.3.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 13.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : android 10.1.2, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 22 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.11.0
   native-run (update available: 1.7.0)   : 1.4.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3 (/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.11.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v14.19.1 (/Users/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.16
   OS                : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode             : Xcode 13.0 Build version 13A233


Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2


java version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.16+11-LTS-199)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.16+11-LTS-199, mixed mode)
javac 11.0.16


.zprofile:
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.1.1-all/1wqbeia0d49252rmlcr6o8lbl/gradle-7.1.1/bin:$GRADLE_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/bin:/Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.16.jdk/Contents/Home


<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="33" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />


Plugins:
cordova-annotated-plugin-android 1.0.4 "cordova-annotated-plugin-android"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-androidx 3.0.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.9.2 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics 6.1.0 "FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging 6.1.1 "FirebaseMessagingPlugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.3 "LocalNotification"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-purchases 2.0.0 "Purchases"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 6.0.0 "Cordova SQLite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova-support-android-plugin 1.0.2 "cordova-support-android-plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.4.0 "cordova-support-google-services"


Recent package updates
"@angular/fire": "~7.4.1",
"firebase": "~9.9.3",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^6.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^6.1.1",
```

Comment: Recent package updates: 
"@angular/fire": "~7.4.1",
"firebase": "~9.9.3",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^6.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^6.1.1",

Comment: @Souleste All 4 of those were major updates.

Comment: for me I needed to set `android:exported="true"` in the main activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I had previously discovered and fixed that. I was still having issues and decided to roll my project forward to Cordova 11. I did that and updated every plugin to the latest. I worked through some compilation errors, but finally got it compiling again. I noticed 2 errors in my event log now though: Android Studio has failed to load the environment from '/bin/zsh'. Integration with tools that rely on environment variables may work incorrectly - even though I see my ENV vars when i check Terminal. And Git is not installed - even though I see I have 2.30.1

Comment: I worked through those issues. It builds and compiles with success messages. I updated Android Studio to the latest, along with all the plugins and packages. Everything is up to date. Still not getting the app to fully install to device or emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this by rolling back to Android compile & target SDK 32. I noticed a new error about: Launchable activity must be exported. I had previously added a config hook to set the MainActvity to export=false. Upgrading Android required me to switch that to true. Lost 3 weeks of time upgrading the project and my machine to discover it was something simple. It works now though!

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.19.0 (/Users/jkufrin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.16
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.3.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 13.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 11.0.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.4) : 0.11.0
   native-run (update available: 1.7.1)   : 1.4.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3 (/Users/jkufrin/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.11.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v14.19.1 (/Users/jkufrin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.16
   OS                : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode             : Xcode 13.0 Build version 13A233
```